# can't get updated state value inside method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna stop the looping when stopState is true.

The stopState is updated when I click the stop button. but inside the startIncrement method, the stopState is always false.

This is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
  const [stop, setStop] = useState(false)

  function Delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }

  async function startIncrement(){
    for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
      console.log(stop) // always false even when i click the stop button
      if(stop) i = 2000;
      setNum(i)
      await Delay(1000)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <main>
      <p>stop: {stop ? "true" : "false"}</p>
      <p onClick={startIncrement}>{num}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setStop(true)}>stop</button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: Its because you called setStop after the startIncrement function, thats y its not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

In order to stop the previously excuted function, you will have to invoke a `clean up` function.

#### Detail on how it works:

In react, each render has it's own props and state, and we can explain this in action:

1. First, you excuted the function `startIncrement()`, at the time of excution, and at that perticular render phase, the value of `stop` is false;
2. Every time the `num` value changes, the page renders, and it just keep going... (excute below code, you can see console prints "renders!")
3. Then you click `setStop(true)` button, and at this particular render, `stop` === true.

However, these two steps involves two different renders, and each renders' state and everything else (props, effect...), does not affect each other, therefore, your `stop` value in the function never changes.

Here's an alternative to achieve the same:

```
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
  const [stop, setStop] = useState(null)
  console.log("renders!")

  useEffect(() => {
    const run = setInterval(() => {
      if(stop === false && num < 100) setNum(num + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(run) // clean up function
  }, [num, stop]);
  
  return (
    <main>
      <p>stop: {stop ? "true" : "false"}</p>
      <p>{num}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setStop(false)}>start</button>
      <button onClick={() => setStop(true)}>stop</button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

The clean up function in useEffect can be seen as a "undo" function.

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-hill-bew8b4?file=/src/App.js), you can read more about side effect from [this post in Dan Abramov's blog](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state)